# List-style-type used as background

Tags: html, css, list

I have a list of items display as a list with the css attribute `list-style-type: disc;`.
Just below the list, I have a last item which is add separatly but I wan't it to be displayed just as if it would be part of the list.

So I am looking for a way a display this disc bullet via CSS with something like the `background` attribute for instance.

I kow I could add an image but I am trying to find another way to add the bullet just to be sure that all my bullet look alike.

You can see what I mean [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GEK3L/1/)

Any idea?

P.S: I have no way of adding this last item to the list so I have to find a workaround to display this bullet only via CSS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Please posty your HTML and css or show a jsFiddle

Comment: sorry for this, I've just added a jsFiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create a css style for separate in wich you can writte this :

```
separate { padding-left:30px; height:20px; background-image:url(yourpath/smal-image-circle.png); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:top left;}
```

Note that the image in background in your div should have a small size
Thanks. Oscar Nsarhaza

Comment: Thanks Oscar and welcome here! I could add it as an image but I would prefer to do it via ths CSS disc bullet directly (to be sure that it looks exactly the same). Maybe there is no way of doing it, and I will have to create a image for the bullet.

Comment: well actually, I gave up and went to this. Thanks @oscar!